# Angular directive attr.$observe work only when is created

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

i have a directive with an observer on `data-color` attribute.

```
# datepicker-directive.coffee
app
.directive 'datepicker', ->
    {
        restrict: 'A'
        require: '?ngModel'
        link: (scope, el, attrs, controller) ->
            el.datepicker({
                language: 'es'
                autoclose: true
            })
            # Update start-date when changeDate
            attrs.$observe 'startDate', (value) ->
                console.log 'startDate'
                el.datepicker 'setStartDate', value
            # Update end-date when changed
            attrs.$observe 'endDate', (value) ->
                console.log 'endDate'
                el.datepicker 'setEndDate', value
            # We have Controller then wire it up
            el.on 'changeDate', (ev) ->
                scope.$apply ->
                    controller.$setViewValue ev.date
            # Garbage collector
            scope.$on '$destroy', ->
                datepicker = el.data 'datepicker'
                if datepicker
                    el.picker.remove()
                    el.data 'datepicker', null
            return
    }
```

in the template i use the directive like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ns.int_date_l" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-end-date="{{ns.int_date_r}}" datepicker>
<input type="text" ng-model="ns.int_date_r" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-start-date="{{ns.int_date_l}}" datepicker>
```

when my Controller run the first time the message "startDate" and "endDate" is showed in the console, but when the `ns.int_date_l` or `ns.int_date_r` change,  the `data-start-date` and `data-end-date`values in the dom changes but the `$observe` is not triggered. **the question is why?**

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WrSD/2) :( but is not working

Comment: Sounds like the problem isn't here. Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which reproduces it?

Comment: @Blackhole I will show the whole picture

Comment: Can you try it without the {{}}, that is `data-end-date="ns.int_date_r"`?

Comment: @callmekatootie `$observe` is waiting the interpolate result without `{{}}` i get an error